# Will apple let you use a uiwebview for a site that is not your own?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Will apple let you use a UIWebView that is not your own? For example if I want to have a view controller for live weather updates, could I just create a UIWebView for something like weather.com or do I have to create a site with the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

UiWebviews can have whatever you want